# Powering Pico and stepper motor though solar panels

Tags: voltage-regulator, solar-cell, stepper-motor, raspberry-pi-pico

**The main question:** Should I power the motor and Pico with a separate set of solar panels or is it solvable in one circuit?

**Explanation:** I am not a total beginner, but did not do electronics for about 10 years so... I might as well ask and learn.

This circuit I made in [circuit diagram](https://crcit.net/c/97306a55606549a6bf7eb89cf6291ee2) shows my setup so far. It doesn't power the Pico and the motor, but I powered the Pico exactly like this before. The [program on the Pico](https://github.com/akosnikhazy/Raspberry-Pico-Projects/blob/main/stepper-motor-with-buttons.py) makes the stepper motor change direction on any button press, it is named main.py and it works when I use the USB port, so that is not the problem (as far as troubleshooting goes).

**edit:** the motor is an SM-28BYJ-48-5V

My measurements:

**The solar panels output:** 20.6 V and 10 mA (when I measure out of circuit)

**Between the solar panels and GND:** 2.5 V and 3.1 mA

[image]

Comment: At 10ma you won't be running much at all.  The quiescent current for just the 5v regulator is 4-6ma.  (The solar cell components in the diagram say 30ma, still likely not enough for a stepper motor).

Comment: Replace however L7805 with a low power "buck" converter ... But comment for the stepper motor always applies as well. What kind of stepper is it?

Comment: @Antonio51 the motor is a SM-28BYJ-48-5V. It runs from the Pico-s output alright when I use USB.

Comment: Ok. Don't know the specification "current". Will try to measure. Do you know that this "unipolar" stepper (5 wires) can be converted to a "bipolar" stepper (NB: it needs than a "bipolar" driver)? You have "just" to cut one "+5V" internal wire and not use the red external wire. Torque should be "higher" if I remember well. Ok, you must "open" the blue plastic to do it, perhaps a bit complicated (I did it one time).

Comment: If of interest https://ardufocus.com/howto/28byj-48-bipolar-hw-mod/

Comment: NB: your schematics do not show any decoupling capacitors. Don't forget to use it.

Comment: @Antonio51 thanks I look in to this. Also capacitors I did not know I should use, reading about it helps a lot.

Comment: Replace L7805 with something like this https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mpq4568.html . You should use also 2 supercapacitors (serially wired with resistors adjusting voltage // 2.7V - 100 F) at power supply output for storing energy and using when necessary (for motor).

Comment: What is ... "Between the solar panels and GND: 2.5 V and 3.1 mA" ?

Answer (score 1):

I should test something like this (idea)[image]: